# Removing all values from HashMap but keeping the keys?

Tags: java, for-loop, data-structures, hashmap

I am trying to delete all `values` associated with all `keys` in my `HashMap`, but still *keep the keys*.

Is the below correct / the most efficient way to do so?

```
 for (Map.Entry<Kennel, List<Dog>> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey().getId();
            List<Dog> dogList = entry.getValue();

            //Loop through the list associated with each key and delete each Dog in the list
            for (int i=0; i<dogList.size(); i++){

                dogService.delete(dogList.get(i));
                dogService.save(dogList.get(i));


            }

        }
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to accomplish here but if you just want the unique keys then probably you should be using a `HashSet` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `Map.keySet()` will return all the keys, if you put them in a new set, you've got a copy of just the keys.

Comment: I just want to remove all the values that are in the HashMap, I am doing so they are Dogs that are being "released" from the kennel and I am looking to delete them from the DB

Comment: What is `dogService`

Comment: @java123999 You want to put the values to null?

Comment: The inner loop could be converted to a enhanced for loop too. That may be more efficient for some `List` classes... Also can dogs occur multiple lists? Is repeatedly deleting them necessary? If yes, is there a big performance impact of unnecessary delete calls?

Comment: @java123999 That's not **the problem** you're trying to solve, that's **the solution** you think is appropriate.

Comment: Is your "DB" this `HashMap`? Like some POC application? Or do you want the keys of the dogs you want to delete from an actual DB? If it's the latter, you're probably looking at this the wrong way

Comment: Given your code, I don't think you need to delete the values at all. You may get further by reconsidering what you need to achieve, and how you're approaching the solution. What you have asked for is both odd, and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler:

```
for(dogs : hashMap.values()) {
    for(dog : dogs) {
        dogService.delete(dog);
        dogService.save(dog);
    }
    dogs.clear();
}
```

Comment: What about the delete method also>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish here but if you just want the unique keys then probably you should be using a `HashSet` instead of `HashMap`.

But, if you want to perform the deletion you can just do the following:

```
for (Kennel key : hashMap.keySet()) {
    hashMap.put(key, null);
}
```

I have written `Kennel key` assuming that key of your `HashMap` is of type `Kennel`.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants

Comment: @EngineerDollery Are you sure? *I am trying to delete all values associated with all keys in my HashMap, but still keep the keys.* I understand that he wants exactly the same from the above statement.

Comment: @mks `Kennel` actually.

Comment: I didn't see any mention of removing duplicate keys...

Comment: @mks He is doing `getId()` and then casting it to String.

Comment: @EngineerDollery What do you mean by *Duplicate Keys*?

Comment: this will throw `ConcurrentModificationException` in case of `HashMap` and NPE in case of `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: @user2004685 removed my comment, but still key is not List<Dog>

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I don't understand why. This works for me: http://ideone.com/pJR5lY

Comment: Given the value is a list, and assuming each key has a list not a null, you'd be better with `((List)hashMap.get(key)).clear()'.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Yes, it might be but what's wrong with `null`. Is there a problem with this approach that you have down-voted it? Why do you have to keep the reference to an empty list if the ultimate goal is to just hold back the keys? Why don't just `null` it and let GC do it's work?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou : I'm not so sure. Here only the values are modified. The key set remains exactly the same... My test also says: "No exception".

Comment: @fabian Exactly my point.

Comment: @fabian yes guys you're right: no exception in this case. But still a bad practice imho.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Yeah, I hope OP has some non-debatable reason for using `HashMap` instead of `HashSet` and deleting the values.

Comment: @user2004685 -- you asked why is an empty list better than null? Because there is no chance of concurrent modification exception, even in multi-threaded code, and there is no chance of ever getting a null pointer exception, and there is no need to deal with nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You could use at the end:

```
hashMap.put(entry.getKey(), null);
```

removing the whole list, but if you want put new dogs into it in the future (as I think you want), and your dog lists are modifiable, the following approach is more memory-friendly:

```
for (Map.Entry<Kennel, List<Dog>> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey().getId();
    Iterator<Dog> it = entry.getValue().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Dog dog = it.next();
        dogService.delete(dog);
        dogService.save(dog);
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

since you avoid allocating new lists in the future. Notice also the usage of `it.remove()` that allows deletion while iterating

Comment: What do you mean by *if you want to use it in the future*?

Comment: just edited my answer

Comment: Well if he want to put new values in the future he can always do `hashMap.put(key, new ArrayList<Dogs>());`

Comment: he will be allocating a new array list and this can be avoided by reusing the existent